# DateTime Comparison in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I am doing comparison between several dates in my stored procedure.

```
    TODAY := TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || 
             ' 09:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

    IF PREVIOUS_DATE < TODAY AND 
       TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= TODAY THEN
        -- do something
    ELSE
        -- do something else
```

When I set `CURRENT_DATE = SYSDATE`, it did not get into the `IF` part. Can someone tell me where did i do wrong?

Comment: Why do you convert `SYSDATE` first to a character literal just to convert it back to a `DATE` afterwards? This is totally useless and due to the `MON` format bound to fail in different NLS environments. `today := sysdate` is much safer and correct as well. And converting a  `CURRENT_DATE` which is a date to a `DATE` using `to_date()` is useless just as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name While I agree wholeheartedly that 'MON' as part of a format mask should be avoided whenever possible, in this case, it should work in any NLS setting since the OP is using MON consistently (unless the to and fro conversions are performed in a different session with different NLS settings) - or am I mistaken?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry for the parameter CURRENT_DATE, i didnt notice it is a function in oracle, my actual parameter name is CUR_DATE, just to make it clear so i rewrite it with CURRENT_DATE

Comment: But still: converting sysdate back and forth does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "CURRENT_DATE is of type VARCHAR2 "

Well that scuppers my first idea 8-)

<s>But I think the problem is in your use of `CURRENT_DATE`.  Assuming that is the Oracle function there are two potential problems:</s>

1. CURRENT_DATE is a DATE datatype and so has a time element.  There's no point in casting it to a date.
2. CURRENT_DATE returns a value adjusted for the system timezone.  Which is presumably the point of your IF test.  But do you know what the values are?

But it remains a straightforward debugging task.  Check your values to understand what's happening.  Here is an example using DBMS_OUTPUT (AKA The Devil's Debugger) because I don't know if you're working in an environment with better tools.

```
TODAY := trunc(sysdate) + 9/24;

dbms_output.put_line('TODAY = '||to_char(today, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
dbms_output.put_line('PREVIOUS_DATE = '||to_char(previous_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
dbms_output.put_line('CURRENT_DATE = '||current_date);


IF PREVIOUS_DATE < TODAY AND 
   to_date(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= TODAY
THEN 
    ....
```

Might as well simplify your code at the same time.

Remember, to see output from DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE you need to SET SERVEROUTPUT ON for whatever client you're using.

---

Incidentally, it is bad practice to declare variables which share the same name as Oracle built-ins.  This is why it is a good idea to add a scoping prefix (`l_` for local, `p_` for parameter, etc) to our declarations.  We don't have to do the full Hungarian to get a lot of benefit.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is of type VARCHAR2 and receives input like `24-APR-2013 16:15:17`
btw, never notice of the trunc function before, it simplify my code a lot. thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - We can override Oracle's CURRENT_DATE with our own local declaration.  Buit as I say, it's bad practice.

Comment: @APC: are you sure you can create your own function that doesn't require the use of `()`? I think if you create your own function named `current_date` the only way to use it would be: `current_date()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it doesn't have to be a function.  I created a VARCHAR2(20) variable of that name.  I'm pretty sure the OP has a VARCHAR2 parameter or local variable.  Difficult to know for sure without seeing their whole code.